# layer on the center entirely

Tags: html, css

how to make the layer is shown in the center of the browser window entirely.

Here is a description of styles for a layer:

```
    #centerLayer {
        position: absolute;
        width: 1280px;
        height: 1500px;
        left: 50%;
        top: 50%;
        margin-left: -150px;
        margin-top: -100px;
        background-color: #e9cb99;
        background-image: url("bg.jpg");
        background: url("bg.jpg") #e9cb99;
        padding: 10px;
        overflow: auto;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

## [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/crcsz416/2/)

```
#centerLayer {
    position: absolute;
    width: 1280px; 
    height: 1500px;
    left: 50%; 
    top: 50%; 
    margin-left:-640px;/*** width/2 ***/
    margin-top:-750px;/*** height/2 ***/  
    background-color:#e9cb99;
    background-image:url("bg.jpg");
    background: url("bg.jpg") #e9cb99; 
    padding: 10px;
    overflow: auto; 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this: http://jsfiddle.net/xBRq9/54/

```
#centerLayer {
    position: absolute;
    top:0;
    bottom:0;
    left:0;
    right:0;
    margin:0 auto;
    margin-top:100px;
    margin-botton:100px;
    width:50%;
    height:50%;
    background-color:#333;
 }
```